# Galois representations on étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbf{Q}$.
Does there exist a prime $\ell$ such that the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$ on $H^j(X_{\overline{\mathbf{Q}}},\mathbf{Z}_{\ell})$ factors through a finite quotient?

Comment: I’m wandering if the op was thinking to the case $X$ has a proper smooth model over $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{Z})$. Maybe in this situation the answer is yes?

Comment: @user104832 I don't think this is true for the projective line over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: By the Weil conjectures, you know what the eigenvlaues of Frobenius are not roots of unity unless $j=0$. So it's essentially never true.